# Kendo ASP.NET Core Language

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

On my developer machine i have polish language system, but i need to develop all pages in english. I am working with Sample Telerik C# ASP.NET Core MVC Application.

My Razor code is currently:

```
<p>CurrentCulture: @Html.Raw(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString())</p>
<p>CurrentUICulture: @Html.Raw(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.ToString())</p>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikAspNetCoreApp2.Models.OrderViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.OrderID).Filterable(false);
    })
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

HTML result is:

```
<p>CurrentCulture: en-US</p>
<p>CurrentUICulture: en-US</p>
<div id="grid" name="grid"></div><script>kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({"groupable":{"enabled":true,"messages":{
"empty":"Przeciągnij nagłówek kolumny i upuść go tutaj aby pogrupować według tej kolumny"}},"columns":[{"title":"Order ID","field":"OrderID","filterable":false,"encoded":true},{"title":"Freight","field":"Freight","filterable":{"messages":{"info":"Pokaż wiersze o wartościach które","isTrue":"prawda","isFalse":"fałsz","filter":"Filtr","clear":"Wyczyść filtr","and":"Oraz","or":"lub","selectValue":"-Wybierz wartość-","value":"Wartość","cancel":"Anuluj","selectedItemsFormat":"{0} selected items"} ....
```

HTML Rendered code contains valid Culture Info=en-US, but Kendo Grid messages are in polish language. How to force Kendo to use English language? Is it also possible to disable this messages? I would like to have short javascript as it is in pure Kendo JS.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to also set your culture client side and be sure you deploy with the culture support files for the languages your application supports.

```
kendo.culture("en-US");

kendo.culture("pl-PL");
```